# jquery - how to make sure only one event execute the result

Tags: jquery

First of all I have searched many times in this forum but none is satisfied me.

Straight to the point, I have these codes

http://jsfiddle.net/amaleen123/PjscF/

The question is, how I want to make 'unbind' focusout (or dont make the focusout appear on the console) when there is click button clicked?

You can see in the console as a result.

Thank you.

This is use jQuery 1.4.4. So please dont solve it by using .on() or .off() because it wont work.

Comment: And do you need both click and focus out with the same function? if you click button focusout on input will start so it could be enough just to put the code there

Comment: The main problem is that `focusout` is triggered _before_ `click`. That's why you can't unbind it after it happened.
You should find different way depending on conditions of your task, because it is hard to imagine what do you want and why is it so bad to write the value to console twice.

Comment: I would suggest to the requester to have focus out only. But you know.. client 'always right' .LoL

Comment: Forgive me if it sound like a silly question. But perhaps in the future it might be useful. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a litle hack - using setTimeout to delay function in focusout, and setting a variable that will check if button was clicked. Not saying it is the best solution, but it is working... http://jsfiddle.net/PjscF/6/

Comment: I think I can use this. Thanks Uriel :)